# How to change navbar dropdown click color (Bootstrap using bootswatch theme)

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to figure out how to change the colour of a navbar dropdown click colour. I am using a theme that modifies the colours for Bootstrap (specifically, Journal theme)

Here is a video of the issue https://i.gyazo.com/09bed7887cf59f7e1e0131fd8edb0ddc.mp4

Here is my code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
<a class="navbar-brand">NAME</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Project showcase
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="projects/discordbot.html">DOTA 2 Discord bot</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="projects/connect4.html">Connect 4 using TypeScript</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="projects/dailyweatherapp.html">Dailyweatherapp using Electron</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My CSS stylesheet theme
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/4/journal/bootstrap.min.css">`

All the CSS that I have looked up found doesn't seem to solve my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, what you want to control here is called the **active** state of a `dropdown-item`. It becomes active when you click and remains active while you keep holding the mouse button down.

In general, all links have an active state as well as a normal state along with a hover state (and visited state).

Here's the css rule set for the active state of a `dropdown-item` in Bootstrap 4:

```
.dropdown-item.active, .dropdown-item:active {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: darkviolet;
}
```

I used "darkviolet" as the background color there but, of course, you can customize it as needed.

Here's the full working snippet (click "run code snippet" below and expand to full page):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
<style>
    .dropdown-item.active, .dropdown-item:active {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: darkviolet;
    }
</style>
   
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand">NAME</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Project showcase
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="projects/discordbot.html">DOTA 2 Discord bot</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="projects/connect4.html">Connect 4 using TypeScript</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="projects/dailyweatherapp.html">Dailyweatherapp using Electron</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```